# A seemingly strange OAuthException

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth

I am learning to build fb apps, and on the very first attempt, I get this strange OAuthException. The tutorial clearly mentions that I need to pass redirect_uri, client_secret, client_id and code(from the app auth phase). But when the flow completes, instead of getting an access token here is the JSON error object I get:

```
{"error":{"message":"client_secret should not be passed to \/oauth\/access_token\/","type":"OAuthException"}}
```

EDIT: this is the snippet I'm using to build the url(pardon the excessive 2nd line, please)

```
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token/"
url += "?" 
url += urllib.urlencode([('client_id',client_id),
                           ('redirect_uri', redirect_uri),
                           ('client_secret', client_secret),
                           ('code', code)])
```

where the variables hold correct values.(checked > 5 times)

Comment: Very strange, as you certainly should should be passing client_secret! Just to cover the obvious, it is https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token you are using, correct? And https for certain?

Comment: @FloydWilburn yes, according to my knowledge, everything is fine... I just edited the question to add the code that builds the url. Have a look.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should remove the / immediately after access_token in the url so that it reads `graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?` followed by your parameters. If that doesn't do it, please show an entire sample url you have generated (with the real client_secret x'ed out of course) since I am not familiar enough with urllib.urlencode to be sure of the formatting, although that part looks right at a glance.

Comment: I'm quite experienced in encoding urls :) So be sure with that. basically urllib.urlencode([("x","y"), ('a','b')]) returns "x=y&a=b" taking care of the % substitutions. I'll try removing the trailing "/".

Comment: that was awesome @floyd, it worked. When can I see you so I can hug you?? :P :) Actually it's a shame on FB API developers that they can't handle such a trivial case.